# How to adjust the cost function for rprop in Accord?

Tags: backpropagation, accord.net

I am playing with Accord.net and seem to be unable to find detailed documentation anywhere, sadly.

I would like to try different cost functions for an activation network with a resilient backpropagation teacher. What is the default? Least squares? How can I change it to, say, cross entropy?